# Why is 'for examples' wrong?

Tags: nouns, countable-nouns

If you want to take an example or *several* example*s*, you use the phrase 'for example,' not 'for example*s*.' Though the word 'example' is a countable noun, why is 'for example*s*' wrong?

Comment: Because you can only list one example at a time, perhaps chained to others with "and also consider" or some such.  If you are going to list Fred, John, and Frank as examples (not chained) you should say "... and consider the examples of Fred, John, and Frank ..." or some such.

Comment: In my view it's not necessarily wrong,  just not idiomatic.

Comment: if you're going to give **plural** examples, examples include: "examples include A, B, C" or "with examples being A, B, C" or "some examples are A, B, C".  You hear those forms all the time - it's totally normal.  In contrast, if you are going to give **one** example, obviously you have to use a singular.

Comment: @brasshat hmm, what's an example of what you are thinking of?  A plural is a plural.  You can most certainly use "for examples" if you offer **plural examples**:  it's common to say "Blah blah, for examples, you need only look at A, B, C" or "Blah blah, for examples of that, you need only look at A, B, C."

Comment: You can certainly use *examples* as a plural, but "for example" is kind of a stock phrase.  In the sentence, "For example, A, or B, or C", you're still considering each of them as an individual example.

Answer (score 3):

When you say "for example" you're referring to the idea of "example".  The "for" isn't a way to shorten "To further illustrate my point here is a list of examples".  In this way "example" isn't countable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it, but even if used correctly, it will sound wrong to people, and will likely distract from the message you are trying to send.

**For examples**, see [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+example%2C+for+examples&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfor%20example%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20examples%3B%2Cc0) and search results [here](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q="for+examples%2C+see") and [here](http://www.google.com/search?safe=off&client=opera&hs=At8&q="for+examples"&oq="for+examples").

Answer (score 1):

The *Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary* interprets the phrase "for example" as an idiom separate from the definitions of the individual word "example". See [here](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/example). Interestingly, even though the dictionary defines "for example" as "used when you are mentioning ***a*** specific person or thing..." (emphasis added), it gives a plural case as an example:

> A lot of my friends were there—John and Linda, *for example*.

At least by the *Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary*, both "for example" (as an idiom) and "for examples" (direct use of the countable noun) should be acceptable for your plural case.